# Was ist das Gegenteil von "tief" bei den Maßen eines Körpers (z.B. Möbel)?

Tags: single-word-request

Die Maße von Möbeln werden oft in Höhe, Breite und Tiefe angegeben.

Wenn ich nun ein Möbelstück beschreibe, nenne ich es entsprechend *hoch* oder *niedrig*, *breit* oder *schmal*. Aber wie drücke ich aus, dass es es eine geringe Tiefe hat? Das einzige einzelne Wort was mir hierzu einfällt ist *flach*.

Das scheint mir aber zumindest uneindeutig, schließlich kann sich *flach* auch einfach auf die Beschaffenheit der Oberfläche beziehen. Gibt es da einen passenderen Begriff?

Comment: Gefällt dir *seicht*?

Comment: @Janka Danke, würde ich aber nicht mit Gegenständen assoziieren - eher etwa mit Wasser.

Comment: Wäre "dünn" ein Kandidatwort?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### [flach](https://dwds.de/wb/flach)

Bei Gegenständen, Schränken und Kommoden (und auch Gewässern!) mit geringer Tiefe spricht man in der Regel von **flach**. Anders ist das bei Tischen und Kisten, dort ist ihre geringe *Höhe* flach.

Beispiele:

[Flachbildfernseher](https://dwds.de/?q=Flachbildfernseher&from=wb) (Verwendungsbeispiele im Zeitungskorpus)
[Flacher Wandschrank](https://www.google.de/search?q=flacher%20wandschrank&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ) (Google Bildersuche)
[Flacher Schuhschrank](https://www.google.de/search?q=flacher%20schuhschrank&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ) (Google Bildersuche)

Comment: +1 Man denke besonders an den *Flachbildschirm*, dessen wesentliche Eigenschaft ja nicht die ebene Oberfläche (auch wenn das vielleicht mal so war), sondern geringe Tiefe ist.

Comment: @tofro: ganz genau!

Comment: Ich bin am Überlegen, ob die Einwände, die man haben könnte, "flach" als "nicht tief" anzusehen, nicht vielleicht aus einem "Verständnis-Anglizismus" herrühren - *flat* hat nicht dieselben Bedeutungen wie "flach", sondern meint tatsächlich hauptsächlich die Oberflächenbeschaffenheit und ist im Englischen kein Antonym von *deep*.

Comment: @tofro: das mag sein, denn im Englischen spricht man eher von *shallow*. Das ist im Deutschen anders. Die Frage nach einem "seichten" Schrank wird ein Möbelhändler mit einem ebensolchen Blick erwidern. :D

Answer (score 5):

Wie von Beta angedeutet, wird neben »flach« auch »dünn« verwendet, es hängt vom Gegenstand ab. Auch »schmal« kommt vor.

**flach**

> - eine flache Flasche in der Tasche haben ([Flachmann](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Flachmann))

**dünn**

> - dünne Bretter sind schnell durchbohrt (verwandt: Dünnbrettbohrer)
> - ein dünnes Buch ist schnell gelesen
> - das Brot in dünne Scheiben schneiden
> - dünne Fensterscheiben kosten Energie
> - ihr dünnes Kleid trägt sie im Sommer

**schmal**

> - [ein schmales Geländer](https://holzer-architektur.de/tag/gelaender/)

Im literarischen Bereich sind auch andere Adjektive möglich, etwa wenn du das Zimmer eines Armen beschreibst.

> Auf dem Boden abgelatschte Schuhe, an der Wand ein dürres Sideboard.

Comment: Gefällt mir auch gut: ein **dünner** Bilderrahmen.

Answer (score 2):

"Flach" würde ich als Ersatz für "niedrig" einstufen, ebenso wie "untief", welches sich auch ein wenig aufdrängt.

Nur Umschreibungen aus mehreren Wörtern würden mir einfallen:

- schmal in der Tiefe
- von geringer Tiefe

Comment: "Flach" scheint absolut gängig zu sein: https://www.deinschrank.de/flacher-schrank.php

Comment: Woran erkennt man auf der Seite, worauf sich "flach" bezieht?